# Solve a system of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the following system: $$x \frac{dx}{dt} + y \frac{dy}{dt} = 1$$ $$(y-2t) \frac{dx}{dt} - (x-2t) \frac{dy}{dt} = 0$$ Solve for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$.

The original problem is to find under which conditions this system has solution. However, is it possible to solve this system directly?

Comment: The original problem should clue you in to the questions of whether you can just find solutions directly: You'll need to determine additional conditions under which this system even has a solution.  If those conditions aren't met, there will likely be *no* solution.  That is, you'll need to find under which conditions this system has a solution, so there's no way of getting around the original problem.

Comment: From which book is this question from?

Comment: Actually, the question is from the lecture notes of my differential equation class.